# format code appears twice error while inserting DATETIME from C# to Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, insert-query

I am facing the below oracle error for the query

**Insert Query:**

```
INSERT INTO WINBACK_REFERRAL_CODES
  (REFERRAL_CODE, IS_DELETED,  CREATED_BY, 
   CREATED_DT,
   MODIFIED_BY,
   MODIFIED_DT, DELETED_BY,  DELETED_DT)
values
  ('sfsdfsd',     'N',         'LA\a03789',
   To_date('4/18/2013 3:57:47 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
   '',
   To_date('','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
   '',
   To_date('4/18/2013 3:57:47 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MM:SS AM'));
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

Can someone please help me resolving this issue. I am trying to insert date and time in this format **4/18/2013 3:57:47 PM** to oracle DB.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as correct; it's strange to see so many upvotes for the lone answer, and yet it isn't marked as correct :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`To_date('4/18/2013 3:57:47 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MM:SS AM')` should be rewritten to `To_date('4/18/2013 3:57:47 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')`. Note the change from MM to MI.